# How to treat all warnings as errors except those related to adding -fvisibility-inlines-hidden

Tags: c++, g++, compiler-warnings, gcc-warning

We have a large C++ project with lots of templates, and using `-fvisibility-inlines-hidden` reduces the final binary size significantly (~15%).

However, there is a particular shared library where I get this warning, which is treated as an error:

> declared with greater visibility than the type of its field (`-Werror=attributes`)

I can solve this by adding:

1. `-Wno-attributes`/`-Wno-error=attributes` or
2. `-fno-visibility-inlines-hidden`

However, 1. is too broad; I still want to treat other attribute related warnings as errors, and 2. removes the benefits of `-fno-visibility-inlines-hidden`.

Is there a way to treat warnings about visibility alone as non-errors?

Comment: How are you building the project? Your build tool should allow you to override the compilation option for that shared library.

Comment: I am able to override the flags at compile time and can add `-fno-visibility-inlines-hidden` easily.  However, I would like to treat all warnings (including those about attributes) as errors except for those about visibility.  This errors out because I also use `-Werror`